# Java Array list adding only 1 item(the last key)while iterating over keys in a JSON object

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm trying to get all the keys within a specific JSON Object but only the last key is obtained.

```
   public void setUpSearch(JSONObject data_json){

    Iterator<String> keys = data_json.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        //get the key
        String key = keys.next();
        scripts = new ArrayList<String>();
        scripts.add(key);
        Log.i(TAG, key);
        Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(scripts));
    }
```

Logtagging key shows all keys (around 300 of em), however logtagging scripts shows only the last one.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Also, please do remember to accept your answers (all of them) if they have given you satisfactory answers (by clicking on the tick mark on the left of the answers), it would be helpful to the community –

Comment: I will :-) accept em

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is a BUG in your code. `ArrayList` initialization should be outside loop, otherwise you're overwriting previous one every time.

Use below code:

```
public void setUpSearch(JSONObject data_json){

    Iterator<String> keys = data_json.keys();
     scripts = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        //get the key
        String key = keys.next();
        scripts.add(key);
        Log.i(TAG, key);
        Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(scripts));
    }
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Ill accept your answer in 10 min